# Google Search - Bandwidth Usage (Msxml2.xmlhttp60 -vs- Msxml2.SERVER.xmlhttp)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, msxml

Working with a VBA workbook to archive results from Google. The following code can perform unlimited searches, provided they are about one second apart.

```
`Dim XMLHTTP As Object
`Dim HTML As Object
`Dim URL as string

`Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
`Set HTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
`URL = https://www.google.com/search?q=Stack+Exchange

`XMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
`XMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
`XMLHTTP.send

`HTML.body.innerhtml = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
```

Problem is too much bandwidth usage. Msxml2.SERVER.xmlhttp seems to pull unnecessary data, probably the image files.

Msxml2.xmlhttp60 utilizes about 80% less bandwidth than Msxml2.SERVER.xmlhttp. Problem with that, after about 1,000 searches google puts a block on xmlhttp60. This doesn’t occur when using SERVER.xmlhttp...

Comment: Not sure why you've tagged this `c#` or `.net`.

Comment: Oh I thought the object was available in those languages as well.